# ¿Cómo pasar un DataGrid a un Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, crystal-reports

Tengo un DataGridView y quiero que con un botón se muestre un reporte de crystal reports, pero sin consulta SQL.

Así es como lleno mi GridView:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ToString());
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from table where cod_user='"+ Session["Cod_user"]+"'", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
gridview1.Visible = true;
gridview1.DataSource = dt;
gridview1.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Comment: No publiques dos veces la misma pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que los datos del datagrid los tienes en un DataSet y que el informe lo has diseñado con la base de datos de este DataSet:

```
InformeListado cr = new InformeListado();
cr.SetDataSource(datos);
this.CRV.ReportSource = cr;
```

Y debe de cargarte el informe con los datos, y mucho mas rápido que haciendo la consulta SQL dentro del informe.

Saludos

Comment: gracias por responder, ya edite la pregunta con el codigo con que lleno mi gridview @Juanjo